# Why does my code not return query results?

Tags: scala, sqlite, async-await, concurrency, slick

Creating the database works. SQLite editor returns correct values. Yet, running below code does not return results. I added `println("completed")` to verify this part of code is reached:

```
val setup = DBIO.seq((movies.schema ++ rooms.schema ++ screenings.schema).create,
    movies += (1, "Django", "Quentin Tarantino"),
    rooms += (1, 9, 10),
    screenings += (1, 1, 1, 1, "19:15")
)

val setupFuture = Await.result(db.run(setup),20.second)

println("Screenings")

db.run(screenings.result).onComplete {
    case Success(results) =>  println("completed")  //results.foreach(println)
    case Failure(exception) => println(s"An error has occured: ${exception.getMessage}")
}
```

I get :

```
[2022-11-11 09:51:05,463] [INFO] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] [main] [] - db - Starting...
[2022-11-11 09:51:05,485] [INFO] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] [main] [] - db - Start completed.
Screenings

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: The last instruction is asynchronous. Not sure of what the clean way to do it is, but if you explicitly wait after that instruction and exit from within the `onComplete` you should be able to see something.

Answer (score 1):

In Slick all operations are async.
So your program (= main thread) is finishing before the async db read thread is finished. So in the same way you wait for the `setup` to finish you may block and wait for the query, sth like

```
...
println("Screenings")
val result = Await.result(db.run(screenings.result), 2.seconds)
println(s"Successfully read: ${result.size} elements")
```

However, since blocking somewhat defeats the purpose of reactive programming, you can lock at the end of your program and run all operations in async fashion, sth like:

```
db.run(setup).andThen { case _ =>
  db.run(screenings.result).onComplete {
    case Success(results) =>  println("completed")  //results.foreach(println)
    case Failure(exception) => println(s"An error has occured: ${exception.getMessage}")
  }
}

// We don't want the main thread to finish
System.in.read
```